# is $f$ integrable (measurable)

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that the function

$f: \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}:$
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    1/(x-1)      & \quad \text{if } x \neq 1\\
    0  & \quad \text{if } x=1
  \end{cases} $$  is (not) integrable.
I wanted to prove that the function was measurable, but this is where I'm already stuck. I'm sure it is but I can't give a good prove. Someone who can help with this?

If I could prove that I wanted to prove that if $f$ is integrable then $\int$$|{f}|d\lambda$ is finite.
Now I calculate:

$\lim{t \to \infty}$ [$\int_{-t}^{1}1/(x-1)dx$+$\int_{1}^{t}1/(x-1)dx$]

=$\lim{t \to \infty}$[$[-\ln(1-x)]^{1}_{-t}$+$[\ln(x-1)]^{t}_{1}$]

= $\infty$ so $f$ is not integrable.

I'm just stuck with the first part of my solution. Proving that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ if $x\neq 1$?

Comment: i'm nog sure where you think i wrote something wrong?

Comment: ah yes i see, i changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to show $f$ is measurable you need to show that
$$
\{x: f(x)< c\}
$$
is measurable for all $c$. (Equivalently, one can change $<$ to $\leq$, $\geq$, or $>$). It should be pretty easy to break down $c$ into cases and show that these sets amount to intervals, which are measurable.